# How to pull specific object from Json String

Tags: java, json

I am new to Json Parsing issue I have the below Json object and I need to get the User object from the below Json

```
{
  "aud": "RoomyClinetApps",
  "sub": "AAAA",
  "User": {
    "firtsName": "Godavarthi",
    "LastName": "chaitanya"
  },
  "iss": "Roomy",
  "iat": 1499279510
}
```

The below is the code I am trying to pull the User object where the the above json is in jsonInString variable when i trying t print I am getting null

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            User user= mapper.readValue(jsonInString.toString(), User.class);

 System.out.println(user.getFirtsName()); --> Null 


public class User {
    @JsonProperty
    private String firtsName;
    @JsonProperty
    private String LastName;
}
```

Could some one please Provide me a working code which is more appreciable.

Thanks
Chaitanya

Comment: `User` is not at the root of that JSON.

Comment: Specify what error message you are getting. Looks like `mapper.readValue(jsonInString.toString(), User.class)` will return an exception, as the whole JSON can't be converted to **User**.

Comment: @Manindar They mentioned they don't get an error. The property simply contains `null`. They've set `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` to `false`.

Comment: Hi  @Manindar when i try to print  user.getFirtsName() i am getting null value no exception i am facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested the below code. It worked for me. Try this once.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String jsonInString = "{\n"
                + "  \"aud\": \"RoomyClinetApps\",\n"
                + "  \"sub\": \"AAAA\",\n"
                + "  \"user\": {\n"
                + "    \"firtsName\": \"Godavarthi\",\n"
                + "    \"LastName\": \"chaitanya\"\n"
                + "  },\n"
                + "  \"iss\": \"Roomy\",\n"
                + "  \"iat\": 1499279510\n"
                + "}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        JsonObject jobj = mapper.readValue(jsonInString.toString(), JsonObject.class);

        System.out.println(jobj.getUser().getFirtsName());
    }

}

class User {

    private String firtsName;
    private String LastName;

    public String getFirtsName() {
        return firtsName;
    }

    public void setFirtsName(String firtsName) {
        this.firtsName = firtsName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String LastName) {
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }

}

class JsonObject {

    private String aud;
    private String sub;
    private User user;
    private String iss;
    private long iat;

    public String getAud() {
        return aud;
    }

    public void setAud(String aud) {
        this.aud = aud;
    }

    public String getSub() {
        return sub;
    }

    public void setSub(String sub) {
        this.sub = sub;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getIss() {
        return iss;
    }

    public void setIss(String iss) {
        this.iss = iss;
    }

    public long getIat() {
        return iat;
    }

    public void setIat(long iat) {
        this.iat = iat;
    }

}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hi @Manindar the code which you share is working fine but i am reciving the Json string from  JWT decrypted token as below so when i applied the same ode on my string it is failing "Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "User " and my json string is {"aud":"RoomyClinetApps","sub":"AAAA","User":{"firtsName":"Godavarthi","LastName":"chaitanya"},"iss":"Roomy","iat":1499312212}

Comment: In **JsonObject** class update the User class reference variable name from user to **User**. It will work for you. Accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Thanks Bro its working its casesentive you save me i changed it worked

Answer (score -1):

```
public class User {
    @JsonProperty
    private String firtsName;
    @JsonProperty
    private String LastName;
}

public class JsonObject{
public string aud;
public String sub;
public User user;
public String iss;
public long iat;

}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            JsonObject user= mapper.readValue(jsonInString.toString(), JsonObject.class);
```

Comment: I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.Roomy.JwtKey.main(JwtKey.java:50)